# CSS Background position top right add a margin?

Tags: css

So I have the following mark up :

```
    background: #7BC145 url(/images/ill_people_leadGen.png) no-repeat right top;
```

And its nearly perfect but i just want to add a bit of margin on top of the image, just wondering how I could add that to above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`background: #7BC145 url(/images/ill_people_leadGen.png) no-repeat right 10px;`

Answer (score 3):

Say you wanted 5 pixels of "margin":

```css
/**                         replace 'top' with this vvv */
background: #7BC145 url("REDACTED") no-repeat right 5px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
background: #7BC145 url(/images/ill_people_leadGen.png) no-repeat 100% 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin-top:10px;` to the same line `background: #7BC145 url(/images/ill_people_leadGen.png) no-repeat right top; margin-top:10px;`

Comment: Note that the space added by the margin will not be filled with the element's background color.